# How to do one time registration in android?

Tags: android, registration, shared

In my android application, I want to show the registration page only at the time of registration after that it will directly go to the main activity, doesn't go for registration page again if I open.

I did like this,It works but.

if I open my app and close it suddenly before registration process, the registration page didn't appear for the next time, without registration.
how can I avoid that.

How to write a condition to disappear the activity after the registration process.

```
  SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Track.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Editor ed = pref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                ed.commit();
            }
```

Guys please help!

Answer (score 0):

you are in currect way, save sharedpreferences for this.

When user successfull register in your app, at that time save sharepreferences.

In onCreate method, if no sharepreferences found then forward to registration page.

Hi you can save sharedpreferences using bellow code.
This is the standard method for write shared preferences.

```
/**
 * write SharedPreferences
 * @param context
 * @param name, name of preferences
 * @param value, value of preferences 
 */
public static void writePreferences(Context context,String name,String value)
{
    SharedPreferences setting= context.getSharedPreferences("Give_your_filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=setting.edit();
    editor.putString(name, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Save your preferences.

Follow this link [click here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response.could you please tell how to save the shared prefernce.because i didn't get you thats y

Comment: Please check this answer now. I update it, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences _RegPref;
boolean _UserType = "";
```

You have to check shref pref before setcontentview method Like:

```
    _RegPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("LoginPref", 0);
    _UserType = _RegPref.getString("REGISTERD", _UserType);
     if (_UserType==true) {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(_ctx, YourActivity.class));
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_new_screen, R.anim.exit_old_screen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
           set contentview("your register activity view");
        }
```

after the registration is succesful, save the values in shred pref like:

```
   Editor prefsEditor = _RegPref.edit();
   _UserType = false;
   prefsEditor.putString("REGISTERD", _UserType);
   prefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: getstring and putstring getting error like this                        " The method putString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences.Editor is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)"

Comment: ahh,that's my code mate, you can use boolean. you have to customize codse according to your requirement.

Comment: still have the problem